# Javascript reload, but keep post variables

Tags: javascript, post, reload

I'm working on a script, and if a button is pressed, I want the page to reload. However, I want to keep the current values of my POST-variables.

I'm using JavaScript, and I've tried `location.reload()`, but I lose the variable values. However, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (refresh), I get the alert box which asks if I want to keep the POST-variables.

Does anyone know how to keep POST-variables when you reload a page using JavaScript?

Comment: try setting a cookie or local storage

Answer (score 0):

In the `onclick` handler for the button you could create a form programmatically, fill it with `hidden` inputs that reflect the names and values of your variables and finally submit that form.

Answer (score -1):

You will have 2 opportunities:

1. Store the post variables in a hidden form an submit this via javascript
2. Use session handling

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: have you ever seen post variables in javascript??

Comment: So there's no function which does exactly the same as control+r?

Comment: ctrl+r is a forced reload. asking for keeping the post values is done by the browser, not by the script :)

Comment: @Yami var something = <?php echo POST["something_else"]; ?>;

Comment: I like your idea about session handling, it filled the bill for me right proper :)